# Floating Point Exception C++ Why and what is it?

Tags: c++, floating-point

I'm building a program for the Euler projects question 3, and while that might not really matter as a result I'm current trying to make this code take a number and test if it is prime or not. Now then before I get to troubleshoot the function it gives me the error "floating point exception" right after inputting the number. Here's the code:

```
int main()
{
    int input;
    cout << "Enter number: " << endl;
    cin>> input;
    int i = input/2;
    int c;
    for (i>0; i--;) {
        c= input%i;
        if (c==0 || i == 1)
            cout << "not prime" << endl;
        else
            cout << "prime" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

so essentially why is it giving me a floating point exception and what does that even mean?

Comment: Something is wrong with your for loop.

Comment: the floating point exception has many reasons but depending on your code, I do agree with Pete and I think c= input%i; is the cause of the problem and I hope my answer helps you..

Answer (score 52, accepted):

A "[floating point number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point)" is how computers usually represent numbers that are not integers -- basically, a number with a decimal point. In C++ you declare them with `float` instead of `int`. A floating point exception is an error that occurs when you try to do something impossible with a floating point number, such as divide by zero.

Comment: Okay, well let me make sure I understand my own code before I try to fix it. The for lop will only execute if i > 0 right? Then the only time it will divide later is c= input%i So it should never divide by 0?

Comment: If you look carefully at your loop, you'll see there is a way that its body can get run once with i == 0.

Comment: if i == 1? So a for loop's increment/decrement happens at the end of the loop even though you write it at the top?

Comment: Yes, thats the entire reason for a for loop.  The loop runs, then it does something (in your case i--) then it runs the loop again until the condition at the top is no longer true.

Comment: lol, yeah, it wasn't working correctly after I fixed the floating point issue but I'm sure you can work it out.  If not, just post back! =)

Comment: This answer is just wrong. The name "floating point exception" is a historical misnomer. Floating point division by zero is well-defined (per Annex F/IEEE754) and does not produce any signal. In OP's code, it's the way integer division by zero, which is **undefined behavior**, manifests on the particular implementation OP is using.

Comment: @R, I asked a related question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52612895/should-divide-by-zero-raise-an-exception  My reading of the wikipedia entry for IEEE754 is that divide by zero does produce a signal and it is clearly listed as such in the VS2015 exceptions list.  However, as per your comment above, the exception never gets raised, even with /fp:except set

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE fp division by zero is specified in IEEE 754-2008 section 7.3 *to signal* although it has an exact infinite result. (Annex F compliance is technically optional as well.)

Answer (score 45):

```
for (i>0; i--;)
```

is probably wrong and should be

```
for (; i>0; i--)
```

instead. Note where I put the semicolons. The condition goes **in the middle**, not at the start.

Comment: Yes, but that's not the reason for the floating point exception

Comment: @Anonymous Indirectly, it is. The misplacement of the semicolons allowed `i` to be `0` (which the condition `i>0` would not have alowed).

Answer (score 14):

Lots of reasons for a floating point exception.  Looking at your code your for loop seems to be a bit "incorrect".  Looks like a possible division by zero.

```
for (i>0; i--;){
c= input%i;
```

Thats division by zero at some point since you are decrementing i.

Comment: so the for loop automatically decrements i the first time through?

Comment: I think you need to make some use of breakpoints and try to think through the solution a bit more.  You dont want us to just give you an answer that will work, do you?

Answer (score 9):

Since this page is the number 1 result for the google search "c++ floating point exception", I want to add another thing that can cause such a problem: use of undefined variables.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is in the for loop in the code snippet:
    for (i > 0; i--;)

Here, your intention seems to be **entering the loop if (i > 0)** and 
decrement the value of i by one **after the completion of for loop**.

Does it work like that? lets see.

Look at the for() loop syntax:

```
**for ( initialization; condition check; increment/decrement ) {  
    statements;  
}**
```

Initialization gets executed only once in the beginning of the loop. 
Pay close attention to ";" in your code snippet and map it with for loop syntax.

Initialization : i > 0 : Gets executed only once. Doesn't have any impact in your code.

Condition check : i -- : post decrement.

```
              Here, i is used for condition check and then it is decremented. 
              Decremented value will be used in statements within for loop. 
              This condition check is working as increment/decrement too in your code.
```

Lets stop here and see floating point exception.

what is it? One easy example is Divide by 0. Same is happening with your code.

When i reaches 1 in condition check, condition check validates to be true.
Because of post decrement i will be 0 when it enters for loop.

```
Modulo operation at line #9 results in divide by zero operation.
```

With this background you should be able to fix the problem in for loop.